# How to get the value of a row from view with a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am trying to get the value of a row inside a specific line using activerecord querying. I already went through all the rails documentation but can't seem to find my way out.

So, the table I'm talking about contains those rows:

> id, flaggable_type, flaggable_id, flagger_type, reason, created_at,
>   updated_at and flag_processed_at

And I'm trying to get the value of flag_processed_at with this:

```
<% flagged_unprocessed = current_message_flaggings.find(resource.id).flag_processed_at%>
```

I have this error

```
11:37:18 web.1    | ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `flag_processed_at' for #<Enumerator: [237]:find(238)>):
11:37:18 web.1    |     1: <% flagged = current_message_flaggings.include?(resource.id) %>
11:37:18 web.1    |     2: <% flagged_unprocessed = current_message_flaggings.find(resource.id).flag_processed_at%>
11:37:18 web.1    |     3: 
11:37:18 web.1    |     4: <% if resource.archived_by?(current_user) %>
11:37:18 web.1    |     5:   <%= render partial: 'app/messages/message/archived', locals: { message: resource } %>
11:37:18 web.1    |   app/views/app/messages/_message.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_app_messages__message_html_erb__2724530553012578480_69900141016240'
11:37:18 web.1    |   app/views/app/conversations/show.html.erb:20:in `block in _app_views_app_conversations_show_html_erb__3548922752939129799_69900161876900'
11:37:18 web.1    |   app/views/app/conversations/show.html.erb:17:in `_app_views_app_conversations_show_html_erb__3548922752939129799_69900161876900'
11:37:18 web.1    | 
11:37:18 web.1    |
```

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: I'm confused; the `find` ActiveRecord method is on an AR class, not a collection of elements. The Ruby `find` expects a block.

Comment: @DaveNewton http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-find

Comment: @ArupRakshit Oh, I don't even know if I knew that one.

Comment: I think, OP's code can have NoMethod error if `nil` is found..

Comment: The error is "undefined method `flag_processed_at'" I am trying to find it's empty or not.

Comment: Ok, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails returns an *Enumerator* class when you call *find* from an *Array*:

```
YourModel.where(id: xxx).to_a.find(xxx)
```

returns an *Enumerator*

Be sure that your *current_message_flaggings* var isn't an *Array*

Comment: Actually, current_message_flaggings was an array, thanks.